# Junit test cases for multiple dependent project in POM.xml

Tags: maven, junit, maven-2, junit4

I have a project Test-A, in this I have junit test class for the application.
Now, I have another project called Test-B, in this I have junit test class for the application.

Test-B, I have included project-A i.e modified POM.xml and included as:

POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.abc.test-A</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestA</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

question: 
When I run mvn test for Test-B project, this has to run Test-A junit test files also. how can I run this kind of tests?

I am junit 4.9 version.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the [Maven Source Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/index.html) to package the test source.

Here is an example for the build plugin to package the test source when you *install* or *deploy* the project:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

You will have to add the dependency for the tests as a `test-jar` type:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.abc.test-A</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestA</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now you have access to the tests from artifact TestA that you can run directly.

Answer (score 0):

Running tests for your project B will not run tests for any dependency. For example your project would also have a dependency to junit. You don't expect those tests to run.

Comment: my requirement is that one to run, i.e from project-B run Junit test cases for project-A.